# React Native Navigation: Go to specific stack navigation screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation 5.

At the top I have a Drawer navigator, with the following screens:

```
  <Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen name="One" component={StackNavigatorOne} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Two" component={StackNavigatorTwo} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Three" component={StackNavigatorThree} />
  <Drawer.Navigator/>
```

Within `StackNavigatorOne`, I have a stack navigator,

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen3} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

In the StackNavigatorOne, the default order of screens is Screen1, Screen2, and Screen3, so that when this stack navigator is called, it shows Screen1 by default. I don't want to change this order.

However, from the Drawer Navigator, when a user clicks, `DrawerScreen One`, I want the user to go to `Screen2` in `StackNavigatorOne`. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

In React Navigation, you can check [Nested Navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#passing-params-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator).

Select your root component `One` first and then select the component inside the `Stack Navigator`.

```
navigation.navigate('One', {
  screen: 'Screen2',
  params: {
    ...
  },
});
```

I assume, Clicking on back will go to your screen from where you navigated. If you want to go to `Screen1`, use `lazy` option as `false`. I've not tested this in `drawerNavigator` but for bottom navigator we used `lazy` option as `false`.

Comment: Using navigation.navigate will work, but in Drawer Navigation, the screen is defined using <Drawer.Screen name="One" component={StackNavigatorOne} /> and in component we specify the stack navigator. There is no place for which screen in the stack navigator.